# Is it possible to change unknown fields to camelCase in Pydantic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pydantic

I have defined a Pydantic schema which accepts unknown fields, like below:

```
from stringcase import camelcase
from pydantic import BaseModel as pydanticBaseModel
class BaseModel(pydanticBaseModel):
    MyName: str = Field(..., alias="myName")
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        extra = Extra.allow
        alias_generator = camelcase
```

Is it possible to convert unknown incoming attributes to camelCase by using `alias_generator` or by any other means? Currently It does not recognize extras.

I want something like below:

```
  inp = {
    "MyName": "Name",
    "Address": "bla bla",
    "Post": "post"
   }

  BaseModel(**inp).dict(by_alias=True)
```

The output should be in camelCase format for known and unknown fields:

```
{
    "myName": "Name",
    "address": "bla bla",
    "post": "post"
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a number of prominent spelling errors, all caused by dropped letters. Is your keyboard malfunctioning?

Comment: oops sorry. I will update.

Comment: Don't forget the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from typing import *
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel, Extra
from caseconverter import camelcase

class MyBase(BaseModel):
    class Config:
       allow_population_by_field_name = True
       extra = Extra.allow
       validate_assignment = True
            
       def get_extra_fields(self):
            return {field: camelcase(field) for field in set(self.__fields_set__ - set(self.__fields__.keys()))}
        
        def camelize(self, to_camel=False):
            extra_fields = self.get_extra_fields()
            for extra_field, camelcase_alias in extra_fields.items():
                current, target = (extra_field, camelcase_alias) if to_camel else (camelcase_alias, extra_field)
                if not hasattr(self, target):
                    value = getattr(self, current, None)
                    setattr(self, target, value)
                    delattr(self, current)

        def dict(self, **kwargs):
            self.camelize(to_camel=kwargs.get("by_alias", False))
            return super().dict(**kwargs)
                    
                    
class Child(MyBase):        
    name: str = Field(None, alias="namE")
    age: int = Field(None, alias="agE")
                
class Parent(MyBase):
    mother: str = Field(None, alias="motheR")
    father: str = Field(None, alias="fatheR")
    children: List[Child] = Field(None, alias="childreN")

# my raw data for testing
data = {
"mother": "bla",
"father": "blabla",
"Out_Sider": "blabla",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "blabla",
        "age": 30,
        "SurName": "blabla",
    },
    {
        "name": "blabla",
        "age": 28,
        "SurName": "blabla",
    }
]
}

parent = Parent(**data)
parent.dict(by_alias=False)
'''Output
    {'mother': 'bla',
    'father': 'blabla',
    'children': [{'name': 'blabla', 'age': 23, 'SurName':'blabla'},
                 {'name': 'blabla', 'age': 34, 'SurName': 'blabla'}],
    'Out_Sider': 'blabla'}
'''

parent.dict(by_alias=True)
'''Output
{'motheR': 'bla',
 'fatheR': 'blabla',
 'childreN': [{'namE': 'blabla', 'agE': 30, 'surName': 'blabla'},
              {'namE': 'blabla', 'agE': 28, 'surName': 'blabla'}],
 'outSider': 'blabla'}
'''
```