# Return all extra passed to pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm trying to get a list of all extra fields not defined in the schema. I saw solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617489/can-i-get-incoming-extra-fields-from-pydantic) but it ignores any nested models. Optimal solution would create a variable in the Pydantic model with extras that I could access after new object with passed data is created but not sure if this is even possible.

Here is the code I'm working with.

Edit: I want `.extras` to be something like a property that returns not just the extra data directly on that instance, but also the extra data on any nested model instances it holds

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, root_validator

unnecessary_data = {
    "name": "Lévy",
    "age": 3,
    "key_parent": "value",  # unnecessary
    "key2_parent": "value2",  # unnecessary x2
    "address": {
        "city": "Wonderland",
        "zip_code": "ABCDE",
        "number": 123,
        "key_child": 1232 # unnecessary x
    }
}


class NewBase(BaseModel):
    versio: Optional[str] = Field(alias='version')  # just to show that it supports alias too
    extra: Dict[str, Any]

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def build_extra(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        all_required_field_names = {field.alias for field in cls.__fields__.values() if field.alias != 'extra'}  # to support alias

        extra: Dict[str, Any] = {}
    for field_name in list(values):
        if field_name not in all_required_field_names:
            extra[field_name] = values.pop(field_name)
    values['extra'] = extra
    return values

class Address(NewBase):

    """
    Cat API Address definition
    """
    city: str
    zip_code: str
    number: int


class CatRequest(NewBase):
    """
    Cat API Request definition
    """
    name: str
    age: int
    address: Address


validated = CatRequest(**unnecessary_data)
print(validated.extras)
>> ["key_parent", "key2_parent", "address.key_child"]
```

Comment: It is not clear, _how_ you want to access all the extra data and in what form it should be presented to you. Do you want `.extras` to be something like a property that returns not just the extra data directly on _that_ instance, but also the extra data on any nested model instances it holds? **Please provide your desired output.**

Comment: Yes @DaniilFajnberg. Thanks for phrasing my thoughts. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version updated to Pydantic v2:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, model_validator

unnecessary_data = {
    "name": "Lévy",
    "age": 3,
    "key_parent": "value",  # unnecessary
    "key2_parent": "value2",  # unnecessary x2
    "address": {
        "city": "Wonderland",
        "zip_code": "ABCDE",
        "number": 123,
        "key_child": 1232 # unnecessary x
    }
}


class NewBase(BaseModel):
    versio: Optional[str] = Field(alias="version", default=None)
    extra: Dict[str, Any] = Field(default={}, exclude=True)

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validator(cls, values):
        extra, valid = {}, {}

        for key, value in values.items():
            if key in cls.model_fields:
                valid[key] = value
            else:
                extra[key] = value

        valid["extra"] = extra
        return valid

    @property
    def extra_flat(self):
        extra_flat = {**self.extra}

        for name, value in self:
            if isinstance(value, NewBase) and value.extra:
                data = {f"{name}.{k}": v for k, v in value.extra_flat.items()}
                extra_flat.update(data)
            
        return extra_flat



class Address(NewBase):

    """
    Cat API Address definition
    """
    city: str
    zip_code: str
    number: int


class CatRequest(NewBase):
    """
    Cat API Request definition
    """
    name: str
    age: int
    address: Address


validated = CatRequest(**unnecessary_data)
print(validated.extra_flat)
```

Which prints:

```
{'key_parent': 'value', 'key2_parent': 'value2', 'address.key_child': 1232}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution does not produce a list of keys as you described, but instead a nested dictionary of key-value-pairs from the `extra` attributes:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import cache
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class NewBase(BaseModel):
    extra: dict[str, Any]

    @classmethod
    @cache
    def required_names(cls) -> set[str]:
        """This is just to make validation more efficient"""
        return {
            field.alias
            for field in cls.__fields__.values()
            if field.alias != 'extra'
        }

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def build_extra(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        extra: dict[str, Any] = {}
        for field_name in list(values.keys()):
            if field_name not in cls.required_names():
                extra[field_name] = values.pop(field_name)
        values['extra'] = extra
        return values

    def get_nested_extras(
        self,
        exclude: list[NewBase] | None = None,
    ) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """Recursively retrieves all nested `extra` attributes."""
        if exclude is None:
            exclude = []
        # To avoid infinite recursion,
        # we need to track which model instances have been checked already:
        if self not in exclude:
            exclude.append(self)
        output = self.extra.copy()
        for field_name in self.__fields__.keys():
            obj = getattr(self, field_name)
            if isinstance(obj, NewBase) and obj not in exclude:
                output[field_name] = obj.get_nested_extras(exclude=exclude)
        return output

    @property
    def extras(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return self.get_nested_extras()


class Address(NewBase):
    city: str
    zip_code: str
    number: int


class CatRequest(NewBase):
    name: str
    age: int
    address: Address


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {
        "name": "Lévy",
        "age": 3,
        "key_parent": "value",  # extra
        "key2_parent": "value2",  # extra
        "address": {
            "city": "Wonderland",
            "zip_code": "ABCDE",
            "number": 123,
            "key_child": 1232  # extra
        }
    }
    validated = CatRequest(**data)
    print(validated.extras)
```

Output:

```
{'key_parent': 'value', 'key2_parent': 'value2', 'address': {'key_child': 1232}}
```

---

If you do want your list of keys instead, you can use these methods:

```py
    ...

    def get_nested_extra_fields(
        self,
        exclude: list[NewBase] | None = None,
    ) -> list[str]:
        """Recursively retrieves all nested `extra` keys."""
        if exclude is None:
            exclude = []
        # To avoid infinite recursion,
        # we need to track which model instances have been checked already:
        if self not in exclude:
            exclude.append(self)
        output = list(self.extra.keys())
        for field_name in self.__fields__.keys():
            obj = getattr(self, field_name)
            if isinstance(obj, NewBase) and obj not in exclude:
                nested_fields = obj.get_nested_extra_fields(exclude=exclude)
                output.extend(f"{field_name}.{k}" for k in nested_fields)
        return output

    @property
    def extra_fields(self) -> list[str]:
        return self.get_nested_extra_fields()
```

Calling `extra_fields` on the previous example model instance gives the following output:

```
['key_parent', 'key2_parent', 'address.key_child']
```

---

Both solutions just recursively iterate over all fields except `extra`.

The annotations assume Python `3.10+`. If this causes problems, replace all types `T | None` with `typing.Optional[T]`. If you are using `<3.9`, (first of all, upgrade your Python :P) replace things like `list[str]` with `typing.List[str]`.

The cached method for retrieving the `required_names` is just for efficiency, so that it is only ever called once for any given model class.

I left the `build_extra` root validator basically unchanged.

**Caveat**:

In the current implementation, if you have nested models in container fields, their extras are ignored. For example, if you had something like `addresses: list[Address]` on your `CatRequest`.

If I find the time, I'll try and amend the solution later. Though I suspect that this may be non-trivial because of the different "shapes" such fields can come in. Also it is not entirely clear how *that* should look in the output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great! Appreciate your time spent on this. Solving problem for me, but also learned few things